# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'load'

Tags: python, opencv

I am using opencv3.1.0.
While I am trying to run:

```
import cv2.cv as cv  
import cv2 

cascade = cv.Load('/usr/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')
```

I find that cv2.cv is not in opencv3, so I change cv2.cv to cv2
and then I get the error message in the title.

Any thoughts? 
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to load a classifier from a file, correct?
According to the OpenCV3 documentation you should use CascadeClassifier for this.
Example:

```
import cv2
cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/usr/share/OpenCV/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')
```

Source: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html